# Unit testing HttpContext Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net

I am using [HttpSimulator](http://nuget.org/packages/HttpSimulator/) for unit testing. I am testing one method that has deeper in code chain call Response.Redirect. I am facing here with problem. I'm getting

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message= Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Web
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()
       at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
       at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
       at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse)
```

Then I reflected HttpApplication type and found mentioned method :

```
public void CompleteRequest()
{
    this._stepManager.CompleteRequest();
}
```

I am initializing HttpApplication on one of the following ways :

```
 HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance = new HttpApplication();
 // or with Mock framework
 var httpApplicationMock = new Mock<HttpApplication>()
 var applicationInstance = httpApplicationMock.Object;
```

As I got from ASP documentation, _stepManager is in charge for Module and Handler execution order and harmonization. This field is initialized depends on whether application is under Classic or Integrated mode.

Then I have called in my test:

```
object stepManager = typeof(HttpApplication).GetField("_stepManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance);
```

I got that stepManager is null, that is expected from above exception. StepManager is initialized within method:

```
internal void InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers)
```

So, from this I am not having control how to ensure stepManager to be initialized.

Then I have tried **second scenario**. In this scenario I have tried to initialize ApplicationInstance on other way.

From following link [AppHost.cs](https://github.com/chrisortman/MvcIntegrationTest/blob/master/src/MvcIntegrationTestFramework/Hosting/AppHost.cs)

I have tried to initialize ApplicationInstance like this:

```
private static HttpApplication GetApplicationInstance()
{
   var writer = new StringWriter();
   var workerRequest = new SimpleWorkerRequest("", "", writer);
   var httpContext = new HttpContext(workerRequest);
   return (HttpApplication)getApplicationInstanceMethod.Invoke(null, 
           new object[] { httpContext });
}
```

and I got on lat method's line :

```
InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=-2146233079
Message=This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.
Source=System.Web
StackTrace:
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxTypeInternal()
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType()
    at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.CompileApplication()
    at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.Init()
    at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureInited()
    at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context)
```

I have tried the **third scenario**. I have created custom Response derived from HttpResponseBase that has overrided Redirect method. But I am facing with problem, how to assign created HttpContextBase to the HttpContext.Current. I saw tip on [Sergei's blog](http://techblog.dorogin.com/2012/05/aspnet-httpcontext-vs-httpcontextbase.html)  :

```
HttpContext httpContext = httpContextBase.ApplicationInstance.Context;
```

But it is not possible to set Context on ApplicationInstance. It is null.

Is it possible to solve one of these 3 cases or to take another idea/approach to unit test my scenario?

Comment: So code from https://github.com/chrisortman/MvcIntegrationTest/blob/master/src/MvcIntegrationTestFramework/Hosting/AppHost.cs does not work for some reason?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have tripped-up with ApplicationInstance initialization. Error was : This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.